# using strcpy to store a string that has many variables

Tags: c, string, printf, strcpy

I'm not sure how to word it, so the title may be unclear. Here's the line in question

```
strcpy (stringstore,"int1: %d\nint2: %d\nint3: %d\nint4: %d\nstring1: %s\nstring2: %s\n",int1,int2,int3,int4,string1,string2);
```

This is inside a for loop so the values of the ints and strings are changing. I want to store each string in stringstore. How would I be able to do this?

EDIT: Here is more code.

```
int id;
int year;
char title[30];
char director[30];
double price;
double length;
int i;
char stringstore[300];
FILE *outp;
outp= fopen("CurrentCatalog.txt","w");
for (i = 0;i<=*size;i++)
{
    id = entry[i].id;
    year = entry[i].year;
    strcpy(title,entry[i].title);
    strcpy(director,entry[i].director);
    price = entry[i].price;
    length = entry[i].length;
    fprintf(outp,"ID: %d\nTitle: %s\nDirector: %s\nYear: %d\nPrice: %.2f\nLength: %.2f\n",id,title,director,year,price,length);
}
fclose(outp);
```

Comment: You mean `sprintf` instead of `strcpy`, I guess?

Comment: I don't know what sprintf is.

Comment: Look it up. It's a standard C function and works like you try to use `strcpy` (your call won't compile).

Comment: Have a look at the [C-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) for tutorial and manuals explaining all you need to know:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Answer (score 2):

Always prefer `snprintf` to convert any data's to string. prototypes for `sprintf` and `snprintf`

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

Make the following change in your code

```
snprintf(stringstore,sizeof(stringstore),"int1: %d\nint2: %d\nint3: %d\nint4: %d\nstring1: %s\nstring2: %s\n",int1,int2,int3,int4,string1,string2);
```

Comment: It's not a function in the libraries I have. I am not using C99.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. The function you are looking for is `sprintf()`not `strcpy()`.
Its the same syntax.

```
sprintf(stringstore,"int1: %d\nint2: %d\nint3: %d\nint4: %d\nstring1: %s\nstring2: %s\n",int1,int2,int3,int4,string1,string2);
```

**EDIT:** as suggested by @chris a safer way to do it is to use `snprintf()`

```
char stringstore[500];
snprintf(stringstore, 500, "int1: %d\nint2: %d\nint3: %d\nint4: %d\nstring1: %s\nstring2: %s\n",int1,int2,int3,int4,string1,string2);
```

**EDIT2** From the new code you posted above, I suggest you merge your `sprintf` and your `fprintf`

```
fprintf(outp,"ID: %d\nTitle: %s\nDirector: %s\nYear: %d\nPrice: %.2f\nLength: %.2f\n",id,title,director,year,price,length);
```

Comment: That should be `snprintf`.

Comment: Okay, I did this but I get a different error-- The stack around stringstore is corrupted. How can I fix this?

Comment: Depends on the input stringstore, but yeah.

Comment: @realdealcs, before calling this function, make sure your stringstore is big enough. For instance declare it like `char stringstore[100];`

Comment: @ValentinMercier Yeah i did and now my program crashes, but i dont get the error.

Comment: @realdealcs Make sure stringstore is big enough to receive all the text. If the final outcome is bigger than 100 make your stringstore size bigger

Comment: I made it 200, but it still crashes. I think the problem is from somewhere else. I will take another look at it.

Comment: It is hard to see what goes wrong there. So instead of one line, show us more of your code.

Comment: Try with snprintf and pass 300 as second parameter between stringstore and the main string

Comment: snprintf is undefined. What library is it in?

Comment: It is in stdio. But only since C99. Make sur your compiler has C99 support enabled

Comment: I don't have C99. And my assignment won't be graded using it either so I won't be able to use it.

Comment: I tried it, and it still crashed my program. I will add the call. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I added the entire function definition.

Answer (score 1):

***Regarding*** *...using ***strcpy()*** to store a string that has many variables...*

The short answer is, you don't.  Use `sprintf()` (or one of it's variants) instead.  (see below)

***I want to store each string in stringstore. How would I be able to do this?***
If you want to store each new set of data, without loosing it in subsequent the iterations of the loop, You need to make stringstore an array of strings.  i.e. create it with:

```
char **stringstore = 0;//will provide for an array of strings when memory is allocated
```

Then allocate memory for it.

***Edit***:  (per your comment)

If you do not need to keep previous information, a single string (char array) of sufficient length will work:

```
#define MAX_LEN 280;//arbitrary size choice as you have not specified size in your code
char *stringstore = 0;  
stringstore = malloc(MAX_LEN +1);// +1 for null terminator
```

***Then*** you can place information into stringstore like this:

```
sprintf(stringstore,"int1: %d\nint2: %d\nint3: %d\nint4: %d\nstring1: %s\nstring2: %s\n",int1,int2,int3,int4,string1,string2);
```

Using this method places memory for stringstore onto the heap as opposed to the stack, so you will need to free it when done using it.

```
free(stringstore);
```

***Note:***
There may be other questions you should be asking about your code, such as
*after opening the text file, how do I read the data into my variables?* .
(You open the text file, then enter the loop, but have
never read data from the file to populate the variables used in the loop.)

Comment: I don't want to store the previous. This is only a temporary holder of the string.